# How do I create a list of records in applescript

Tags: applescript, hashtable

I need a list of records created using applescript. I'm trying to create a Java like Hash Table in Applescript.

```
set grocery_list to {"milk", "butter", "eggs"}
set milk to {name:"Whole Milk", quantity:"1 Gallon", brand:"Newland Farms" }
set butter to {name:"Unsalted Butter", quantity:"1 pound", brand:"Land O Lakes"}
set eggs to {name:"Grade A jumbo eggs", quantity:"1 dozen", brand:"Farm Fresh"}
```

I need a way to create this structure in a way, that I can access the following:

Iterate through the list, get the individual items and for each item get the brand.

I tried this

```
say brand of (item 1 of grocery_list)
```

But this gave me an error

```
Can’t get brand of \"milk\"." number -1728 from brand of "milk"
```

Any recommended way to implement this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were close:

```
set milk to {|name|:"Whole Milk", quantity:"1 Gallon", brand:"Newland Farms"}
set butter to {|name|:"Unsalted Butter", quantity:"1 pound", brand:"Land O Lakes"}
set eggs to {|name|:"Grade A jumbo eggs", quantity:"1 dozen", brand:"Farm Fresh"}

set grocery_list to {milk, butter, eggs}

say brand of (item 1 of grocery_list)
```

Comment: Words like name are often reserved. To designate them as variables (not to be confused with properties of another object) you can surround them with ||.

Comment: If the variable is declared elsewhere, the order is not important. However, you created a text list, not a variable list. Notice I did not enclose milk in quotes.